# How to express $x^5$ as a telescoping series

Tags: real-analysis

How do I express $x^5$ as a telescoping series (i.e, $x^5=x^5-x^{a}+x^{a}-x^b+x^b-...)$?

In other words, I must find functions $b(n),c(n),d(n)e(n)$ such that $x^5=(-1)^{b(n)}$$x^{c(n)}$+$(-1)^{d(n)}$$x^{e(n)}$. Please, give me a hint!

Comment: Finite or infinite? There are too many uninteresting ways.

Comment: You mean like $x^5 = (x^5 - x^4) + (x^4 - x^3) + (x^3 - x^2) + (x^2 - x) + (x - 1) + 1$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps this is not what you are looking for, but how about:

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{x^{5-k}}{k!}-\frac{x^{4-k}}{(k+1)!}\right)$$

The factorials are added to ensure convergence. This doesn't work for $x = 0$ though, but it's the only exception.

Alternativelly, you can use:

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{x^{5+k}}{k!}-\frac{x^{6+k}}{(k+1)!}\right)$$

So that it also works for $x = 0$